# How is the `end-of-stream iterator` Created?

Tags: c++, string, stream, iterator

I have the code that reads content of 2 files into 2 `std::string` variables. There is the `assign` member function used. There are `InputIt first` and `InputIt last` passed into it. `InputIt first` gets a `file` variable as an argument. `InputIt last` gets nothing (it is just `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()`).

**Question:** How does `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` construct an end-of-stream iterator, if nothing is passed to it and also, AFAIK, argument order is not guaranteed by the standard?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file_A("A.txt");
  std::ifstream file_B("B.txt");
  std::string content_A;
  std::string content_B;
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> itr_A(file_A);
  std::istreambuf_iterator<char> itr_B(file_B);
  content_A.assign(itr_A, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());  // A.txt
  content_B.assign(itr_B, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());  // B.txt
  file_A.close();
  file_B.close();
  std::cout << '"' << content_A << "\"\n\n";
  std::cout << '"' << content_B << "\"\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to assign some meaning to "end of stream iterator" that it doesn't have. The only thing required from it is to compare equal with iterators that run out of things to read. You can't get any file contents from such iterator. This doesn't require knowing which stream we're dealing with (if `istreambuf_iterator` is a stream member, the default-constructed iterator can just have it zeroed), and constructing it doesn't need to have side-effects (so argument evaluation order doesn't matter).

Comment: `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` is just an empty iterator. When a "real" iterator, like `itr_A` hits EOF, it enters an empty state too. That's all.

Comment: @BoP, do I understand you right that if the `last` iterator is empty (or whatever it is), than it's just not used by the [`assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) method?

Comment: @ENIAC - No, it is used, but with no direct connection to the stream. The initialized iterators hold a pointer to the streambuf, while the end iterator just holds a nullptr. When `itr_A` is done with its stream, it can also make its pointer a nullptr, and then they compare equal.

Comment: @BoP, thank you for explanation! It does makes sense. If you post your comment as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you for your comment! Together with BoP's comments it makes sense to me.